# How to access another class in another package?

Tags: java

I have 2 classes, each is on different folders

Main class src/mainclass/Main.java
Display class src/swingclass/Display.java

Main Class:

```
package src.mainclass;

import src.swingclass.Display;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Display sM = new Display();     
    }
}
```

Display Class:

```
package src.swingclass;

public class Display{
    public Display(){
        System.out.println("Display class");        
    }
}
```

i run it on cmd and it is stated

error: package src.swingclass does not exist

and also, Main class could not see Display class.

overall, i have 3 errors.

I know that using IDE will make this easier, but i want to learn this on cmd. I followed the tutorials on net, but it still has errors.

Comment: what is your order of compiling?

Comment: *i run it on cmd*: how? from which directory? That's the key parts that are missing from your question. BTW, you probably didn't *run* anything. You tried to *compile* the classes. That's quite different.

Comment: Do you use an appropriate directory structure?

Comment: @JBNizet oops sorry. i "compiled" it on cmd.

Comment: That doesn't answer any of my questions. Edit your question, and paste the command you tried to use. Tell us from which directory you executed this command.

Comment: @JBNizet i compiled it inside the folder where i placed my source code.
but it should work right?

Comment: What's not clear in "Edit your question, and paste the command you tried to use. Tell us from which directory you executed this command."?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should get rid of the `src` part of the package, i.e.

```
package swingclass;

...
```

and import it like:

```
import swingclass.Display;
```

Comment: By convention, this is correct, but where is the technical difference?

Comment: @still_learning technical difference is in that fact, that OP seems to be confused with the structure

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove all occurrences of "src." in all files
2. Change to the src directory
3. Type: javac mainclass/Main. java
4. Type: javac swingclass/Display.java
5. Type: java mainclass.Main

Answer (score 0):

Using the `-classpath` flag should help you solve your problem.

```
javac -d "theClassPathNameYouWant" "src/swingclass/Display.java"

javac -d "theClassPathNameYouWant" "src/swingclass/Main.java"

java -classpath "theClassPathNameYouWant" swingclass.Main
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `src` folder level (go inside `src` folder) in your command prompt, and use the commands

```
javac -classpath . src/mainclass/Main.java
```

to compile (this will implicitly compile the `Display` class as well, since it is required by `Main` class) and

```
java -classpath . src/mainclass/Main
```

to run the `Main` class.

`.` indicates the current directory (in your case, `src` folder) relative to which the other paths (to source/class files) are then specified.

Answer (score 0):

javac -d bin -sourcepath src <path to main class from src directory, in your case it will be one folder up from src/mainclass/Main.java>

java -cp bin src.mainclass.Main  (set class path to bin root where class files are, scr is where your package starts)